# What are the inorder and postorder traversals of the following tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

With respect to the following tree:

[image]

1. What is the correct inorder traversal?

   1. U S T X C P Y R B A I G J F N H V T E D L
   2. U S T X C P Y R B A D E I G J F N H V T L
2. What is the correct postorder traversal?

   1. U T S X P R Y C B D I J G N V T H F E L A
   2. U T S X P R Y C B I J G N V T H F E D L A

I evaluated both pairs. But some are saying 1-1 and 2-1 are correct, while others say 1-2 and 2-2 are correct. I'm confused. Which ones are actually correct?

Comment: Neither in-order traversal is correct as it should start with `B`.

Comment: @Welbog: Please show the correct order for inorder traversal. And which one of the postorder traversals do you think is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

inorder:

```
B U S T X C P Y R A D E I G J F N H V T L
```

postorder (2.2 is correct):

```
U T S X P R Y C B I J G N V T H F E D L A
```